# The problem of finding a local minimum of a function

Tags: optimization, program-optimization

I wrote code for the Regular Simplex (RSM) and the Irregular Simplex (Nelder-Mead Method (N-MM)) in Visual Studio in C++. For given functions (quadratic (QF), Rosenbrock with alpha = 1 (RF1), Rosenbrock with alpha = 12 (RF12)), starting points ({-1, -1}, {2, 2}), accuracies (1e- 2, 1e-5) received the number of iterations, functions and cost (in this case, which is equal to the number of calculated functions).

Made conclusions:

1)

(a) For QF and RF1, the minimum point is more accurately found by PSM;

(b) For RF12, the minimum point is more accurately found by N-MM;

2)

(a) In terms of cost, N-MM for RF12 is significantly cheaper than RSM;

(b) In terms of cost, RSM for RF12 is significantly cheaper than N-MM;

3)

With increasing accuracy, the cost and number of iterations increase (remain equal in the case of RF12 (2, 2) N-MM);

4)

A more gully function (RF12 vs RF1) requires more iterations and has a higher cost;

5)

The strongly gully function (RF12) requires more iterations and has a higher cost compared to QF;

6)

RSM and H-MM for gully and quadratic functions work better for a more distant point;

7)

(a) For the nearest point for a quadratic function, RSM works better;

(b) For a strongly gully function (RF12), H-MM performs better.

Are my results plausible? What else would you recommend adding to the output?

How to explain point 6? As I understand it, it is due to the fact that the trajectory of one point goes along a gentler slope, and the second along a steeper one.
[image]

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/165409/755, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/53878/5038.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).